# Existence of a specific continuous function

Tags: general-topology, continuity, connectedness

> Let $(X,d)$ be a connected metric space. Is there a continous function $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ with $f(X)=\{0,1\}$?

I think there isn't such a funcion. The image of a continuous function of a connected metric space should also be connected and $\{0,1\}$ isn't.
Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your argument is correct (that is, assuming that we are dealing with the usual topology on $\{0,1\}$ here).

Furthermore if $X$ is disconnected, then there is always a continuous and surjective function from $X$ onto $\{0,1\}$.